# Como alterar o texto do botão BACK no Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

Queria alterar o Texto que está no botão BACK no IOS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O que eu tentei:**

```
     public override void ViewDidLoad()
            {
                NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem { Title = "Teste" };

                base.ViewDidLoad();

                 //nao funciona NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem { Title = "Teste" };

                    //nao funciona NavigationController.NavigationBar.BackItem.BackBarButtonItem.Title = "teste";
    }

public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
             NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem { Title = "Teste" };

                base.ViewDidLoad();

                 //nao funciona NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem { Title = "Teste" };

                    //nao funciona NavigationController.NavigationBar.BackItem.BackBarButtonItem.Title = "teste";
        }
```

Nenhuma destas formas funcionou.

Comment: se instanciar o botão como `NavigationPage` ao invés de `NavigationItem` não funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte:

```
        this.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem("Novo Texto", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, args) => 
        {
            this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);

        }), true);
```